# Gauss Jordan elimination problem. Is this right?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

so I immediately converted the equations to an augmented matrix and I want to know if I did this correctly:

\begin{matrix}
  2 & 2 & 1 & 0
\\2 & -3 & -4 & 0
\\4 & -1 & -3 & 0 
\end{matrix}

I added some multiple of the first row to the second and third:

\begin{matrix}
  2 & 2 & 1 & 0
\\0 & -5 & -5 & 0
\\0 & -5 & -5 & 0 
\end{matrix}

are these reductions legit? Can I divide by -5 and can I just eliminate a row if it's identical?

\begin{matrix}
  2 & 2 & 1 & 0
\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}

divide row 1 by 2

\begin{matrix}
  1 & 1 & 0.5 & 0
\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}

finally:

\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & -0.5 & 0
\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}

Is that okay?

Comment: The equation in the row you eliminated became 0=0, telling you that the system is underdetermined.

Comment: So there's no solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far so good. Of ourse, you can delete one of two identical rows. The simple explanation is that it makes no difference if a condition (in this case, an equation) is written down once or twice. But you can also argue using Gaussian elimination: subtract one from the other, and you can definitely delete the all zero row that occurs.

But you haven't finished the proof. The question was to provide the answer parametrically. 
The way you carried out the Gaussian elimination process, the variable $z$ is a free variable. 
So $z\in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter (it can be an arbitrary number). 
Now, you can easily express the rest of the variables using $z$. 
From the first equation, you obtain $x= 0.5z$, and from the second, you obtain $y=-z$.

So the set of all solutions of the system is the set of triples $(0.5z, -z,z)$, where $z\in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

What does this $$ \begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & -0.5 & 0
\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}$$

tell you about the solutions of your system?

The first one says $$x- 0.5z=0$$ and the second one says $$y+z=0$$

What you need to do is finding parametric solution for your system.

For example if you let $$z=t$$ then solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ you will be done.